# Enforce class declarations with Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to implement an abstract Hierarchy class. Any Hierarchy object should have a parent (could be null) and a set of children, both of the exact same type as the concrete implementation of Hierarchy. Can this be done with generics, and if not is there any mechanism to enforce this relationship?

Here's what I was thinking so far, but there are issues:

```
public abstract class Hierarchy<T extends Hierarchy<T>> {
    private T parent;
    private Set<T> children;

    public T getRoot() {
        if( parent == null ) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return parent.getRoot();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with `return this`. It gives a compile error because `this` is of type `Hierarchy`, not `T`. I can't cast it, because I don't actually guarantee that `this` is of type `T`. The following declaration would compile just fine:

```
public class B extends Hierarchy<B> {...}
public class A extends Hierarchy<B> {...}
```

So is there any way I can disallow `A extends Hierarchy<B>` declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way I can disallow A extends Hierarchy
>   declarations?

No, it is not possible.

You can do what you want with something like this:

```
public abstract class Hierarchy<T> {
    private T parent;
    private Set<T> children;

    public static <E extends Hierarchy<E>> E getRoot(E x) {
        while (x.parent != null) {
            x = x.parent;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it would still be beneficial to do `Hierarchy<T extends Hierarchy<T>>`